# blocked by CORS policy in ionic-5 angular

Tags: android, angular, ionic5

I am facing this error, can someone please guide me for the same.
I have made configuration in proxy.conf.json
I have set header with base url in user.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class UserService {

    constructor(public http: Http) { }

    yaho() {
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        // headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');


        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        headers.append('appKey', '4d71e017-6896-477b-bb0d-93bb9e6d3224');
        const options = new RequestOptions({ headers });
        const baseURL = 'abx/gas.json';
        console.log('Base url---->' + baseURL);
        const url = 'localhost:8081/abx/gas.json';
        return this.http.get(url, options)
            .pipe(map(res => res.json()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/abx/gas.json' from origin 'http://localhost:8102' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: I have made few changes in proxy.conf.json file
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8081",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot fix your issue by trying to enable CORS in your client. This is a general/ fundamental feature of [http](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and not something specific to ionic or angular. If you have no way to change the back end then you can use a proxy.

"The Ionic CLI introduced the ability to have a proxy server issue requests for you to get around any CORS issues you may have. Since the server is sending a fresh request to your destination, there will be no origin and therefore, no CORS needed"

as described [here](https://ionicframework.com/blog/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/) and example repo [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-proxy-example)

Which I assume is how you are trying to handle CORS request without enabling it in the back end.

Please note that "CORS is only an issue when we are running or testing our app when running ionic serve or ionic run -l."

to setup the proxy:

1. set up the proxies in our ionic.project

> ```
> {
>   "name": "proxy-example",
>   "app_id": "",
>   "proxies": [
>     {
>       "path": "/api",
>       "proxyUrl": "http://cors.api.com/api"
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

2. replace our endpoint URLS to be set to the proxy server
3. run `ionic serve`

Aside from this "The easiest way to handle the CORS problem is to ultimately ask your API provider to allow all hosts"

Comment: I'm doing everything and the proxies dont seem to proxy...

Answer (score 2):

You have to configure your backend to accept CORS, not your frontend

(the headers you're trying to add should be added to the backend not to the angular app)

Comment: May i know the exact location please or any document

Comment: Depends on the server you're using, how are you serving the `localhost:8102` ?

Comment: its ionic ..! when i run ionic serve then its runs on 8102 port number.

Comment: I'm sorry I meant `localhost:8081`

Comment: i have hosted Thingworxs on 8081 port no. On my local machine

Comment: I want to configure from front end only..! I dont want to edit from thingworxs

Comment: can't be, CORS has to be enabled from the backend,
the frontend is trying to access a resource, the backend by default doesn't accept to respond to requests from a different origin (Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing) unless you configure it to

Comment: I am not able to change CORS rule due to security policy, is there any other way to do that

Comment: @Prashant that really depends on your backend stack/setup, you'll need to search/ask for your specific setup (for example how to enable cors for a Laravel app on Heroku)

Comment: @MotassemKassab I understand what you said. I think it is limitation of ionic. As I can not disable CORS for all IP in server side. As ionic using `localhost` proxy to make request. 
In place of ionic wrapper I embedded all html in WebView. Now it is working without compromising backend CORS safety policy.
I don't understand why you all saying; disabling CORS, it will put entire server at risk. Can you explain, I would like to understand.

Comment: @Prashant check out the "Why is CORS important" section https://hackernoon.com/understanding-cors-why-its-important-and-how-it-works